# Amazon Route 53 Domain Issue: Can't go to site without entering www

Tags: amazon-web-services, domain, amazon-route53, domain-transferring

So, I am not sure if there is a duplicate to this - but I have a really wonky situation that happened during an Amazon **Route 53** domain transfer.

I'll start from the beginning:

- I bought a domain and hosting through **Siteground** called [rtd62.com](http://www.rtd62.com/)
- After a year of having the hosting through **Siteground**, I decided to switch to **Amazon Web Services**.
- So I used **Route 53** to do a domain transfer and everything works fine... except there's one odd problem.

If you type in **rtd62.com** into the address bar, the browser throws back a *DNS Error* of **ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**.

But, if I type in **www.rtd62.com**, everything works just fine. Did a miss a record or step during the transfer process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you *do* have proper DNS records for `www.rtd62.com`, you **do not** have a DNS record for `rtd62.com`. You will need to create an `A` record in your Route53 hosted zone pointing `rtd62.com` to `52.3.21.213`.

Alternatively, if you want to simplify things a bit, once you do the above, you can change the record for your `www` host to a `CNAME`, pointing at `rtd62.com`. This way if your server IP changes, you only need to change it in one place in your DNS.

Comment: `CNAME` includes all RR types, so SPF, TXT, all other records are included when you CNAME www to example.com, just be aware.

Comment: @JacobEvans Good point. I checked those before making the suggestion. :)